# Eloquent Javascript Book chapter 5 example about recursion and ancestry

Tags: javascript, recursion

Going through the book eloquent javascript when I came upon this piece of code about summarizing ancestry.  There are a couple of boards out that have gone over different parts of this, but the part I am having trouble with is this chunk:

```
var thisOneCounts = current != person && test ( current );
```

specifically, when is current ever not == to person?  I can't seem to find a situation since current always gets called as person.  But obviously I'm missing something because when I take that bit of code out, it returns a different solution.  Below is the code in total.

```
 function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultVal) {
     function valueFor(person) {
         if (person == null)
             return defaultVal;
         else
             return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]), valueFor(byName[person.father]));
     }
     return valueFor(person);

 }

 function countAncestors(person, test) {
     function combine(current, fromMother, fromFather) {
         var thisOneCounts = current != person && test(current); // **
         return fromMother + fromFather + (thisOneCounts ? 1 : 0);
     }
     return reduceAncestors(person, combine, 0);
 }

 function longLivingPercentage(person) {
     var all = countAncestors(person, function (person) {
         return true;
     });

     var longLiving = countAncestors(person, function (person) {
         return (person.died - person.born) >= 70;
     });
     return longLiving / all;
 }
 console.log(longLivingPercentage(byName["Emile Haverbeke"]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `valueFor()` function in `reduceAncestors()` is called recursively with the parents of the original person, and then the grandparents etc. Those recursive calls may make calls in to `f()`, and `f()` is that `combine()` function from `countAncestors()`.

Thus, the starting person is passed to `reduceAncestors()` first. That calls `f()` (which is that `combine()` inner function) with the results of calling `valueFor()` with the parents. That, in turn, will result in the *mother* being passed to `f()` and the *father* being passed to `f()`. Back in the context of the original call to `countAncestors()`, `person` is still the *original* person, but the passed-in value of `current` to `combine()` will be different (it'll be the mother or father or maternal grandmother/grandfather or paternal grandmother/grandfather etc).

Let's just look at the first call to `countAncestors()` in the `longLivingPercentage()` function. We pass in the starting person and the dummy `test()` that always returns `true`. I don't know what the code expects the genealogy data structure to be, but let's assume it's like this:

```
{
  person: "Bob",
  mother: {
    person: "Mary",
    mother: null,
    father: null
  },
  father: {
    person: "Jim",
    mother: null,
    father: null
  }
}
```

Thus:

1. The `countAncestors()` function is called for Bob.
2. That passes Bob to `reduceAncestors()`, along with a reference to that `combine()` function.
3. In `reduceAncestors()`, `valueFor()` is called for Bob, and since Bob is not null we get to the call to `f()` — which is `combine()` — which needs to pass Bob, the mother, and the father.
4. Before `f()` is called, however, we need to call `valueFor()` with the mother and the father, because the *results* of those calls need to be passed in to `f()`.
5. So `valueFor()` is called with the mother. That *also* wants to call `f()`, and it *also* will need to check the mother and father (that is, Bob's mother's mother and Bob's mother's father).
6. Those two grandparent calls fail fast because they're null, so the call to `f()` for Bob's mother can proceed.
7. Now we're in `combine()`, and the first parameter — `current` — is Bob's mother. The context of that instance of the `combine()` function came from the function call made when `person` was Bob, and Bob is definitely not his own mother.

Comment: Thanks Pointy! I understand now.  current != person in the subsequent recursive calls since current will continually change while person will remain the person from the initial call.  Great help and super fast response.  Thanks a million! been racking my brain all day with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is only one situation that the `current` is equal to `person`. Wich is the original person that passed in the `longLivingPercentage(byName["Emile Haverbeke"])`. For other times, the `current` is Emile Haverbeke's ancestors. Because `person` is Emile Haverbeke, so `person` is not `current` for the all the time except for Emile Haverbeke.

I think the purpose of this code(current != person) is to get rid of the original person from the counted results. In the book, the author did not add `current != person`.